# Evento ng-click no funciona en nuevo HTML generado

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo un evento `ng-click` que no funciona desde mi controlador a pesar de que aparece en el código HTML:

[image: Captura del HTML generado]

Este es el código del evento:

```
$scope.modificar  = function(event){
        var id = event.target.id;
}
```

¿Alguna solución a esto?

Este botón es un *subgrid* que se añade con una función:

```
function boton(accion){
    var cadena = 'valor_00409_20210919_N';
     if(accion=='M'){
                return '<button id="'+cadena+'" class="buttonEdit" ng-click="modificar($event)"><span id="'+cadena+'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>' 
            }else if(accion=='D'){
                return '<button id="'+cadena+'" class="buttonEdit" ng-click="eliminar()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>' 
            }else{
                return '';
            }
  }
```

Comment: ¿Estás usando Angular.js (casi seguro que es éste) o Angular.io? ¿Ese es el código que quieres ejecutar (`$scope.modificar`) o el de abajo (`function boton()`)? ¿Qué función tiene el código de abajo?

Comment: Si, angularjs, genero el botón con la función boton según el valor que le paso y genera en el html ese botón y cuando pulso ejecuto $scope.modificar

Comment: ¿Y qué tienes pensado hacer cuando pulses el botón? ¿Solo obtener el `id` del botón pulsado y nada más?

Comment: Ya estoy empezando a entender el problema. ¿Estás creando HTML dinámico a través de tu propia función en vez de usar las funciones que te proporciona Angular.js? Es decir, ¿para qué has creado la función `boton()` y cuándo la llamas? Esa función es completamente innecesaria y no está integrada con Angular.js, por eso no te funciona `ng-click`.

Comment: exactamente la uso cuando creo el subgrid, al formatear un campo se ejecuta. ¿Cómo podría genera ese html dinámico y que funcione? o es imposible?

Comment: Te doy dos soluciones alternativas a hacerlo de manera nativa en Angular.js, pero te recomiendo integrar tu código en Angular.js y no rehacer la rueda como intentas hacer. Si compartes el código de tu controlador puedo indicarte cómo integrarlo de manera nativa con Angular sin tener que usar trucos alternativos.

Comment: Indicaste que mi respuesta no funciona. Por favor, comparte el código de cómo agregas ese HTML que devuelve esa función a la página para poder decirte la manera correcta de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta corta debería ser:

- **No generes HTML dinámico sin usar Angular.js**.

La respuesta larga es que, si quieres que Angular.js te proporcione funcionalidad en código HTML que no lo ha generado él, debes "ayudar" a Angular.js para conseguir mantener la integración mediante uno de estos dos métodos:

- Compilando los nodos HTML antes o después de enviarlos o generarlos en el DOM.
- Indicando el destino a través del ámbito.

### Compilando el HTML

Hacemos uso del servicio [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) para compilar el HTML de un elemento para que Angular.js se integre en él:

```
$compile(elemento)($scope);
```

Un ejemplo de funcionamiento:

```js
var pruebasApp = angular.module('pruebas', []);

pruebasApp.controller('PruebasController', function PruebasController($scope, $compile) {
  contenedor.innerHTML = "<button ng-click='modificar()'>Pulsa aquí</button>";
  /* Compilamos el HTML recién agregado */
  $compile(contenedor)($scope);
  $scope.modificar = function() {
    console.log("Pulsado");
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.2/angular.min.js" integrity="sha512-7oYXeK0OxTFxndh0erL8FsjGvrl2VMDor6fVqzlLGfwOQQqTbYsGPv4ZZ15QHfSk80doyaM0ZJdvkyDcVO7KFA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<body ng-app="pruebas" ng-controller="PruebasController">
  <p id="contenedor"></p>
</body>
```

### Indicando el destino a través del ámbito

Usamos el evento `onclick` del DOM estándar para que llame a la función deseada dentro del ámbito actual:

```
<button onclick='angular.element(this).scope().modificar()'>
    Pulsa aquí
</button>
```

Donde `angular.element(this).scope()` corresponde a `$scope` en tu controlador.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de uso:

```js
var pruebasApp = angular.module('pruebas', []);

pruebasApp.controller('PruebasController', function PruebasController($scope, $compile) {
  /* Usamos el atributo "onclick" de HTML */
  contenedor.innerHTML = "<button onclick='angular.element(this).scope().modificar()'>Pulsa aquí</button>";
  $compile(contenedor)($scope);
  $scope.modificar = function() {
    console.log("Pulsado");
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.2/angular.min.js" integrity="sha512-7oYXeK0OxTFxndh0erL8FsjGvrl2VMDor6fVqzlLGfwOQQqTbYsGPv4ZZ15QHfSk80doyaM0ZJdvkyDcVO7KFA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<body ng-app="pruebas" ng-controller="PruebasController">
  <p id="contenedor"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Buenas al final si que conseguí que me funcionara. SOolo que ahora tego un problema, como podria añadir modificar una variable que su valor es dinámico.Gracias y disculpa la tardanza

Comment: También es sencillo. Puedes redactar una nueva pregunta proporcionando los datos necesarios (HTML, JavaScript, etc) y dejarme un comentario por aquí para que le eche un vistazo.

Comment: Por cierto, si esta respuesta te ayudó y/o resolvió tu problema, no olvides marcarla como correcta para que se considere respondida.